# jQuery slider index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to duplicate the text inside the `<h1>` tag in the `.slider-item` divs to the anchor tags in the `.bx-pager` div. For example, the anchor in the first `.bx-pager-item` should have the text of the h1 in the first .slider-item div. Then the anchor tag in the second `.bx-pager-item` should have the text of the `<h1>` in the second `.slider-item` div. Is there something wrong with my jQuery code that makes it not do what I want?

My jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#pagination .bx-pager-item").each(function(){
    var whichPos = $(this).index();
    var whichSlide = $('.slider-item').index(whichPos).find('h1').text();
    $(this).find('a').text(whichSlide);
  });
});
```

The pagination:

```
<div id="pagination">
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="#"></a></div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="#"></a></div>
</div>
```

The slider structure is:

```
<div class="bxslider">
  <div class="slider-item">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-item">
    <h1>Header 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var whichSlide = $('.slider-item').index(whichPos).find('h1').text();
```

to:

```
var whichSlide = $('.slider-item').eq(whichPos).find('h1').text();
```

[index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) does not get the nth element, it returns a number.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/JKLbXw

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem.